# Find all documents by array values with a specific order and time-span

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, database

I'm tracking the status of various domains with the following document structure. This is an example of a domain that was registered some time between two checks/updates.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
  "domain" : "example.com", // fake data
  "history" : [ // every time the status is updated it's added here
    {
      "date" : ISODate("..."), // date status updated
      "status" : "inactive", // unregistered
    },
    {
      "date" : ISODate("..."),
      "status" : "active" // registered
    }
  ],
  "length" : 11,
  "status" : "active"
}
```

I'd like to find which domains have been registered within the past week. This query finds domains that have been both inactive and active at some point in my DB.

```
db.domains.find({'history.status': {$all: ['inactive', 'active']}})
```

I'd like to only find domains that have been inactive and active in the order I entered though, or else it also returns domains that have become available. I would also like to only search recent history (one week exactly). Is this possible with one query?

---

EDIT: Realized I can simply require the current (most recent) status of the domain to be "active" to only get those who's most recent availability change was being registered, and not made available. That solves one problem, but the time limit is still an issue.

```
db.domains.find({'history.status': {$all: ['inactive', 'active']}, status: 'active'})
```

---

Edit 2: I was looking at it all wrong. **The following query does what I want**:

```
db.domains.find({history: {$elemMatch: {status: 'inactive', date: {$gte: <week ago>}}}, status: 'active'})
```

I'll leave this question open in case anyone has a more elegant solution.